# Python: How to produce only in sequence combinations from a list of string parts, with use being optional

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

I would like to know how I can produce only in sequence combinations from a list of string parts, with use being optional. I need to do this in Python.

For example:

`Charol(l)ais (cattle)` is my complete string, with the parts in brackets being optional.

From this I would like to produce the following output as an iterable:

```
Charolais
Charollais
Charolais cattle
Charollais cattle
```

Was looking at Python's `itertools` module, since it has combinations; but couldn't figure out how to use this for my scenario.

Comment: What you describe is not permutations. Basically, for each pair of parentheses, you have two options: to include the text in them, or to exclude it. Right? Can the parentheses be nested?

Comment: I don't see any permutation here. The order of the letters are always the same. Please rephrase your question with the proper names. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way)

Comment: I don't have an answer, but sounds like you're looking for a breadth-first iteration rather than a depth first iteration.

Comment: Nesting support would be cool, but probably don't need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to convert the string into a more sensible format. For example, a tuple of all of the options for each part:

```
words = [("Charol",), ("l", ""), ("ais ",), ("cattle", "")]
```

And you can easily put them back together:

```
for p in itertools.product(*words):
    print("".join(p))
```

To create the list, parse the string, e.g.:

```
base = "Charol(l)ais (cattle)"
words = []
start = 0
for i, c in enumerate(base):
    if c == "(":
        words.append((base[start:i],))
        start = i + 1
    elif c == ")":
        words.append((base[start:i], ""))
        start = i + 1
if start < len(base):
    words.append((base[start:],))
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the permutations from `itertools` and denote your optional strings with a special character. Then, you can replace those either with the correct character or an empty string. Or carry on from this idea depending on the exact semantics of your task at hand.